# Why does Index.html work from my Desktop but not as a GitHub web page?

Tags: html, api, geolocation, github-pages

When I save my index.html below to my Desktop and open the file, it works correctly on my browser. But when I create a repository on GitHub and publish it as a webpage only the latitude and longitude values are loaded correctly, while the location and temperature values don't load at all. Does anyone have an idea as to why this would happen?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Geocode  Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lat, lon, api_url;

    $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
          data: '',
          url: "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyCW0lvagDP67ulkwwP7yAIBHJoj2HT0apM",

      success: function(result){
        lat = result['location']['lat'];
        $('#lat').html(lat);
        lon = result['location']['lng'];
                $('#lng').html(lon);

        api_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' +
        lat + '&lon=' +
        lon + '&units=metric&appid=6b897716ef0e040e1f6c854adfb11822';

        $.ajax({
          url : api_url,
          method : 'GET',
          success : function (data) {
            var temprC = data.main.temp;
            var location = data.name;
            var desc = data.weather.description;
            $('#result').text(location);
            var temprF = (temprC * (9/5) + 32);
            $('#temp').text(temprF + '° F');
          }
        });
       }
    });
});
</script>
<span>Your Latitude : </span><span id="lat"></span><br>
<span>Your Longitude : </span><span id="lng"></span><br>
<span>Your Location:  </span><span id="result"></span><br>
<span>The Temp: </span><span id="temp"></span><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because of GitHub Pages are serve with HTTPS. And if you try to send HTTP request on a HTTPS site, the request maybe be blocked.

So that you can get latitude and longitude through `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate`, but you can't get data through `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`.

[This Article](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/) from GitHub may can help you.